# Helping with Gucci like owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

Ive tried as much as I could on creating an owl carousel for a fashion website, I want a similar one that gucci.com has. Image below. I have updated my website and code and looks like this now: ghostparis.com[looks like this now: ghostparis.com] . Okay so progress so far the images are now loading and in a carousel, not playing automatically sadly and critically loading vertically and not horizontally, like if you visit the website in mobile device you will see that the image loads downwards and not sideways like the next image. I dont know how to fix it :( [1](https://ghostparis.com)

[image]

I have tried creating this in code (HTML)

```
<div class="site-blocks-cover" data-aos="fade">
  <div class="backgroundHome">
    <div class="slider_area">
      <div class="slider_active owl-carousel owl-theme">







        <div class="homeslider">
          <div class="item">
            <div class="image1">
                <img src="images/Ghost1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="image2">
                <img src="images/Ghost2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="image3">
                <img src="images/Ghost3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>




        </div>
```

css here:

```
    .backgroundHome{

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

background color red is just for development purposes as its just overriden by image on slider

and javascript I think here is pretty much where my mistake is as its my first time actually creating a slider:

```
var slider1 = function(){

  $('.slider_active').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
  items:1,
  autoplay:true,
  navText:['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
    nav:true,
  dots:true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 800,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            dots:false,
        },
        767:{
            items:1,
            dots:false,
        },
        992:{
            items:1,
            dots:true,
        }
    }
  })


};
slider1();
```

Help with be really much appreciated.

Comment: okay now it doesnt look that bad but images are nested downwards,not sideways